# app do not fit in avd window size

Tags: emulation, android-virtual-device, configure

[app do not fit in A.V.D. window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBofe.png)

When I started android virtual machine , fine. It worked, then the problem started, my app was loaded and was working properly but the only problem was that my app didn't fit in the android virtual machine window size, i tried too search over net but no proper solution was there , do i need to configure virtual machine or need to change its settings? Shall I re install the A.V.D. again? Tried to restart it but nothing happened.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gBofe.png

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your AVD's device size and use 'scale to real size' or similar option given when starting an emulator